# Javascript code is not working in php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have tried some code given below, but javascript is not working on php page. I am a newbie trying to learn code.

```
<section id="cart_items">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive cart_info">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cart_quantity">
                            <div class="checkout">

<p class="price" data-price="4.99">$4.99 per Juice</p>
<p class="description">Quantity:</p>
<input type="text" class="quantity" value="1">

    <p class="total">Total: <span id="total">$4.99</span></p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section> <!--/#cart_items-->
<!--/#do_action-->
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkout").on("keyup", ".quantity", function(){
        var price = +$(".price").data("price");
        var quantity = +$(this).val();
        $("#total").text("$" + price * quantity);
    });
});
</script>
```

Javascript not working,Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its work just add jquery api `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>`